# How to split String and associate a value to another?

Tags: android, string

Sorry just saw your answer now, i´ve been doing some code:
this is my code:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject(reply);



            JSONArray jsonArray = mainJson.getJSONArray("Companies");



            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                 JSONObject objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                 map.put("ID", objJson.getString("CompanyID"));
                 map.put("name", objJson.getString("CompanyName"));
                 mylist.add(map);



                 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                 adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                 spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

but the log says error parsing data or.json.exception!!

Comment: You need to get ID from this response by split this ?

Comment: You mean you want to parse the above json?

Comment: I need to split this because i want to put the names in a spinner, and then when i click on a name it gets the id, how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
    class result {
       item[] items;
    }
    class item {
       int id;
       String name;
    }
    private class itemSerializer implements JsonSerializer<item> {
    @Override
            public User deserialize(JsonElement json, Type type,
    JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
            JsonObject jobject = (JsonObject) json;
            item it = new item();
            it.id = jobject.get("id").getAsInt(), 
            it.name =  jobject.get("name").getAsString()); 
            return it;
           }
    }

com.google.gson.GsonBuilder gson = new GsonBuilder();

    // and to serialize only id and name use custo deserializer:

    gson.registerTypeAdapter(item.class, new itemSerializer());
    result res = new result();
    res = gson.create().fromJson(yourString, res.getClass());
```

then you have to load a List<String> names as ArrayAdapter for the Splitter and possibly an HashMap<String,String> mapNames2Ids to map Name clicked on id